# Mac vscode: multiline with ctrl + mouse click

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to configure vscode on macos to select multiline with `ctrl` + `mouse click` instead of `⌘ Cmd` + `mouse click`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the default is <kbd>option</kbd> + `click`.

You can toggle between <kbd>option</kbd> & <kbd>command</kbd> by changing the respective setting at: `Editor: Multi Cursor Modifier` but doesn't seem to support <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: That's correct but it change to alt instead of ctrl.